# Smoother shading at object loaded via STLLoader

Tags: three.js

[image: screenshot]

model loaded via STLLoader avalaible in THREE.js repo at github loads models  into THREE.BufferGeometry with face normals computed in that painful way. geometry.computeFaceNormals() does not make any difference

```
model.traverse(function (child) {
            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                child.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
            }
        });
        model.traverse(function (child) {
            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                child.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
            }
        });
```

, same with changing THREE.Smooth/FlatShading.

How to make loaded models smoother? Shaders, remap normals?

Comment: You have provided no information about your model, so one can only guess at a solution. If the loaded geometry is of type `THREE.Geometry` (or you convert it to that type), then you can try calling `geometry.mergeVertices()` prior to calling `geometry.computeVertexNormals()`.

Comment: @WestLangley ".mergeVertices ()
Checks for duplicate vertices using hashmap.
Duplicated vertices are removed and faces' vertices are updated. " How it can help? But firs time first - if I use Geometry instead BufferGeometry it is not efficient with models with more triangles.
I told I load it via STLLoader , and it's THREE.BufferGeometry `loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
var file = 'ring.stl';
    loader.load( file, addModel )
function addModel(geometry) {
        model = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
}`
Where material doesn't matter because it works smooth on buil-in geometries.

Comment: I want only know what to do after loading to make it look smoother. And which way is the best. I just feel it should be someting with anisotropic rendering and done by shaders.

Comment: I didn't noticed it's duplicated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35136282/how-to-smooth-mesh-triangles-in-stl-loaded-buffergeometry

Comment: @WestLangley Then I simply convert it back to buffer geometry via .fromGeometry(geometry) - and now I have more fps's and smooth model, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to smooth mesh triangles in STL loaded BufferGeometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35136282/how-to-smooth-mesh-triangles-in-stl-loaded-buffergeometry)